# Using SED to remove a domain name starting with http from result

Tags: sed

I am very new to shell scripting, the command line, sed, awk, etc so bear with me.

I have a script that outputs -

```
Reseller: iwantmyname http://iwantmyname.com
```

I want it to read -

```
Reseller: iwantmyname
```

Dropping anything starting with http

I figured SED would be a good tool but I only have a basic knowledge of it, and the tutorials I've found online seem advanced and difficult for me.

I know the basic is sed `'s/find_this/replace_with_this/'` and I figured I'd replaced the found `http` with `//` or nothing. But I don't know how to search for something that starts with `http` and include EVERYTHING after it. I've looked up regex but that seems quite difficult as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace a white space followed by `http` and rest of row with nothing:

```
's/ http.*//'
```

Comment: Works great. Is there anywhere online that has a good, graduated tutorial on sed, awk, regex not already written for system admins but people just starting out?

Comment: This might help: [35+ Examples of Regex Patterns Using sed and awk in Linux](https://dzone.com/articles/35-examples-of-regex-patterns-using-sed-and-awk-in)

Comment: @PhilHanson I quite like the O'Reilly [sed & awk book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do).